# undefined method `safe_concat' for []:Array in rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I am trying to execute a flash partial like the following:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="flash <%= "#{key}" %>"><%= "#{value}" %></div>
<% end %>
```

And am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `safe_concat' for []:Array
```

The partial is being updated via an ajax request as follows:

```
page.replace_html "flash_messages", :partial => 'layouts/flash', :locals => { :flash => flash }
```

Any ideas? I have never seen something like this before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be the following?

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="flash #{key}"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

There's no need to wrap the `key` and `value` into `"#{}"`. I suppose the nested `<>` is what made it choke on your line.

I can't try so I wouldn't know if it actually can access `key` outside of `<% %>`, so maybe you would need something like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% class_names = "flash #{key}" %>
  <div class="<%= class_names %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried both approaches and same issue. The funny thing is that this doesn't happen if I put the code in the application.html.erb file. For some reason, making it a partial is messing things up... why is very weird.

Comment: Hm, then I guess I'm out of options, my Rails/Ruby knowledge isn't that good.